# The meaning of "let" in theorem statements

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

I want to prove a theorem which starts with the statement

> Let ... then there exists ... .

I want to know the meaning of let in this kind of theorems. Does "let" mean for every or for some of? How can I prove this kind of theorems?

Comment: "Let" is associated with a universal statement.

Comment: @GitGud is right. Sometimes, when you try to prove something, you actually try to make an assumption. Let x be an integer, Let x be an even number etc. These assumptions will first lead to a conclusion and then will help you to prove the required condition.

Comment: so what about "Let ... then there exists ... such that... ." I mean if we have a condition after such that.?

Comment: @user146566 Perhaps reading the relevant section in [How to Prove It](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521675995) will help you.

Answer (score 2):

like this

let there exist some positive number more then $5$,for instance $6$,then there exist such number which makes this $6$ nullified ,or $-6$.it is for some